# Spring Security Prevent multiple logins

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I'm creating a rest API, I want to prevent the same user login to the Spring boot Application. My config is as follows

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .and().sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1);
        
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Also how to send a response to the front end if the user has already logged in. For the moment I can log in to the application on the same browser using multiple tabs. I want to disable this.

This is my controller

```
@PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest){
        try {

            Optional<User> _user = userRepository.findByUsername(loginRequest.getUsername());
            
            if(_user.get().isActive()) {
                if(_user.get().isPasswordReset()) {
                    return ResponseEntity
                            .badRequest()
                            .body(new MessageResponse("Password Rest Required"));
                } else {
                    
                    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));
                    
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                    String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJWTToken(authentication);
                    
                    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
                    List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                            .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    
                    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt, userDetails.getId(), 
                            userDetails.getUsername(), 
                            userDetails.getEmail(), roles, 
                            userDetails.getCompany().getId())); 
                }               
            }else {
                return ResponseEntity
                        .badRequest()
                        .body(new MessageResponse("Current user is inactive! Please contact support team"));
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Bad credentials"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not only for one user, It controls the maximum number of sessions for every user :

```
sessionManagement()
    .maximumSessions(1)
    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
```

reference documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/SessionManagementConfigurer.html

Comment: This does not work, I tried this. please check my controller as well. I'm using JWT auth token to log in, does this have any effect on session management